# How to consume data from Kafka based on time interval using Java

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api

Suppose current time is `10:03`, I have to consume previous `1min` data `(10:01 to 10:02)` again after `1 min (at 10:04)` I will run my job at that time I have to consume data from `10:02 to 10:03`, Using `cron` setup I can run my job for every `1 min` but how can I make sure that it consumes data from `10:01 to 10:02` and after `1 min` it consumes `10:02 to 10:03` in Kafka. I have to consume exactly previous `1 min` of data from Kafka whenever my job runs

Comment: How did you sort it out?